# Any method that executes before willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, rotation

Is there any method that will execute prior to `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`?

This is very important to me because it seems like the view coordinate system switches immediately before this method is executed. I am trying to execute a method immediately before the system has decided to rotate the device, so something along the lines of `- (BOOL)shouldAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation` would seem to be the perfect place to execute such a method (but it doesn't seem to exist in the documentation).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. The bounds have not been transformed at the time it is called.

But:

- These methods are deprecated in iOS 8 (and the entire "rotation" model is completely changed), so don't become reliant upon them.
- In my view it would be better ask yourself why you think you need the view coordinate system in this way. It would be better to position things using constraints that are independent of such considerations.

Comment: See my discussion here for an actual example of doing the kind of thing you're probably thinking of doing: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#SECrotationevents It shows how to do it your way, but then it also goes on to show how to do it better, using constraints. The constraints way transfers well to iOS 8, but the "willRotate" way does not.